# Image upload and jCrop and codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, image-manipulation

I am trying to build a system that allows a user to select an image from their own computer, and crop it using the jCrop tool from jQuery.  My question is can I show the image the user has selected from their system  without uploading it to a system, I dont really want to do two uploads, unless I can do the first upload silently? Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to upload twice. Just upload the image at first time

Use jCrop and send image Thumbnail's coordinates(x,y), width and height.

Resize Image according to them

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, not using JavaScript and HTML (4) at the moment.

Flash can do image processing before upload - [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/) for example can resize images before uploading (doesn't support cropping though), but I don't know an Open Source implementation of a Cropping tool in Flash.

It will probably also be possible using HTML 5.

However, I don't see how you would need two uploads to do this? Isn't it 1. Upload 2. Show with Cropper 3. send Crop info to PHP script that processes the uploaded file?